# How to create custom SKActions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Hello all I want to do is create a SKAction which does something similar to `wheelRight.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 1000);` to a physics object.

Comment: There's a class method for SKAction called customActionWithDuration:actionBlock:. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SKAction runBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runBlock%3a) method:

```
SKAction *changeVelocity = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        wheelRight.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 1000);
    }];
SKAction sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[..., changeVelocity, ..., ...]];
[wheelRight runAction:sequence];
```

Comment: what is the scope of this block? how is it getting wheelRight? is it OK for wheelRight to be null when this action is defined as long as it is populated before the action is actually run? thank you