# Check if touch is active in Sprite Kit (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So, I am developing a game in Sprite Kit for the first time ever. This is a great learning experience for me!

However, I have encountered an issue :( I do not know how to make it so that a function is called repeatedly while a touch is active (for example, a function is called every 0.5 sec that touch is 'touching'). So, I was considering having an SKAction run and then cancel/delete it when touch is released... but I decided against that.

Instead, I was hoping for a function that checks if there is a touch, *but not necessarily that a touch was pressed, released, or changed location*, i.e. check if a touch is touching, period.

If this is not possible, is the easiest way for me to overcome this quandary what I was thinking of initially, or is there something easier?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: How come you decided against using SKAction?

Comment: I decided against using an SKAction for two reasons, one is quite petty come to think of it... 1) I feared that it might get a bit complicated/messy 2) I am not 100% sure how to call a function from an SKAction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you, I would use an `SKAction` (or several) because, in my opinion, it helps keep my code cleaner; you run an `SKAction` in one place and then you don't have to worry about it again. This helps keep the `update` method free of lots of game logic.

In your comment you mentioned not being sure how to call a function using an `SKAction`. You can use `SKAction.runBlock` for that; it takes a closure (or function) that has no arguments and returns `Void`.

Alternatively, you could use `SKAction.customAction...` to create your own action running a function, although it's not appropriate in this situation. The documentation has more information on custom actions, here's a quick example though: [How to create custom SKActions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400928/how-to-create-custom-skactions)

Anyhow, Here's how I'd achieve what you were after:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let actionID = "TouchActionID"

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
        let block = SKAction.runBlock { println("Hello World") }
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, block])

        // Use `actionID`, defined earlier, as the key. 
        // This allows you to cancel the `SKAction`.
        self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence), withKey: actionID)
    }

    // Cancel the SKAction if the touch ended or was cancelled. Cancelling 
    // could occur if the application resigns being active, for example.
    // See UIResponder documentation for more information.
    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        self.removeActionForKey(actionID)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.removeActionForKey(actionID)
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!